# How escape chars in Go Template?

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have this YAML structure:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-04-20T15:18:50Z"
  labels:
    billing: mybilling
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
```

I'm trying to access it over my script but I could not access the "beta.kubernetes.io/os" because the special chars.

```
        {{$os_version := .metadata.labels.beta.kubernetes.io/os }} --> failed
        {{$os_version := .metadata.labels."beta.kubernetes.io/os" }} --> failed
        {{$os_version := .metadata.labels.beta\.kubernetes\.io\/os }} --> failed

        {{$os_version := .metadata.labels.billing }} --> success
```

How to access the metadata ".metadata.labels.beta.kubernetes.io/os"? How to scape this special chars?

Answer (score 3):

The standard library already provides the [index function](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions)

```
{{ index .metadata.labels "beta.kubernetes.io/os" }}
```

In my case:

```
{{$os_version := index .metadata.labels "beta.kubernetes.io/os" -}}  --> works!!!
```